# C struct string error

Tags: c, struct, allocation

Here are some chunks of my code to give you a view of my problem

```
    typedef struct {
    int count;
    char *item;
    int price;
    char *buyer;
    date *date;
    }transaction;

transaction *open(FILE *src, char* path) {
char buffer[100], *token;
int count = 0;
transaction *tlist = (transaction*)malloc(sizeof(transaction));
tlist = alloc(tlist, count);
src = fopen(path, "r");
if (src != NULL) {
    printf("\nSoubor nacten.\n");
}
else {
    printf("\nChyba cteni souboru.\n");
    return NULL;
}
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), src)) {
    tlist = alloc(tlist, count+1);
    token = strtok(buffer, "\t"); //zahodit jméno obchodníka
    tlist[count].count = strtok(NULL, "x");
    tlist[count].item = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    tlist[count].item++;
    tlist[count].item[strlen(tlist[count].item)] = '\0';
    tlist[count].price = atoi(strtok(NULL, "\t "));
    token = strtok(NULL, "\t"); //zahodit md
    tlist[count].buyer = strtok(NULL, "\t");
    tlist[count].date = date_autopsy(strtok(NULL, "\t"));
    count++;
}
fclose(src);
return tlist;
}

transaction *alloc(transaction *tlist, int count) {
if (count == 0) {
    tlist[0].item = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    tlist[0].buyer = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
}
else {
    tlist = (transaction*)realloc(tlist, count * sizeof(transaction));
    tlist[count - 1].item = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    tlist[count - 1].buyer = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
}
return tlist;
}
```

First in `main()`, I create the list

```
transaction *list = (transaction*)malloc(sizeof(transaction));
```

Then with the right command, I call my opening function that loads a file, then it tokens a line from that file into pieces that then puts into the structure. It all works fine.. When I want to print(for testing) tlist[count].item inside the opening function, it prints the right thing. But when I try it outside(in main()), it prints garbage. It somehow works for the date and price parts of sturcture.. I assume the "buyer" string will be broken as well. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you are overwriting the allocated memory with the local buffer for the item , bueyr fields so it is not reflected in the caller function. Modify the code as below

   tlist[count].count = strtok(NULL, "x") -> strcpy(tlist[count].count, strtok(NULL, "x"))

   tlist[count].buyer = strtok(NULL, "\t") -> strcpy(tlist[count].buyer , strtok(NULL, "\t"))

   and also check the tlist[count].date , You should allocate the memory for the date and also use memcpy to copy the contents.
2. Since strtok returns the NULL termintated string what is the use of the following lines ?

   tlist[count].item++;

   tlist[count].item[strlen(tlist[count].item)] = '\0';

Comment: 2. I couldn't separate a string correctly. It strtoks " something" and I want "something", so I increment the pointer. The other line was just my try of solving this problem. I thought those strotoked strings weren't properly ended

Comment: I deleted that 2nd line, used your code and it is working fine now, thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score -1):

strtok holds an internal static buffer which is filled and returned after every call.

somerthing like this:

```
char *strtok(...)
{
  static char buf[XX];

  // get next token

  return buf;
}
```

You are effectively assigning and therefore overwriting the data the pointer points to after every call.
A better use would be to allocate memory for the char * fields and use strcpy for the data returned from strtok

Comment: This is incorrect. strtok() effectively has a `static char *` and the pointers strtok() returns are pointers to the original memory passed to strtok() in the first argument in the call for the first token. strtok() replaces the delimiter characters in this memory with zero bytes to create zero-terminated strings for the individual tokens.